# run a command based on shoutcast listener count

Tags: shell, command, shoutcast, listeners

I have a problem with a small number of corrupt MP3s crashing Ices on a Shoutcast stream. And I'm looking for a way to check the number of listeners connected to a stream and execute a command on the shell if it's below a value which might indicate that it (Ices) may have crashed.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be far easier and more reliable to parse the process list to see if your Ices instance is running.  Can you run scripts on the machine where Ices is running?  Also, have you considered checking to make sure the source stream is connected, rather than looking at listener count?  All of that data is available in the XML that comes back from SHOUTcast.  What version of SHOUTcast are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately I have 8 shoutcast servers and ices sources on this host so checking whether the process is running might be difficult since only 1 stream is affected. Also Ices is crashing but keeps the connection open albeit with no music playing. And I'm using shoutcast 1.9.8...

Comment: That's strange that the connection hangs open when Ices dies off.  If you go into the SHOUTcast admin panel, does it say something like "Stream Status: Stream is up at 24 kbps"?  Or does it indicate that the stream is disconnected?  I ask because I've seen weird situations where the source client will be disconnected, SHOUTcast will know it, but won't switch over to the backup.  I've got a couple solutions for you, but need to know what your SHOUTcast admin panel says about the source connection first.

Comment: I will have to wait for the next crash...